# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

Tags: c#

Table structure is

```
userid int
fname varchar(50)
lname varchar(50)
Email varchar(50)
Phone decimal(18,2)
```

This is procedure

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[AddUser] 
     @userid int,
     @fname varchar(50),
     @lname varchar(50),
     @Email varchar(50),
     @Phone decimal(18,2)
as
    insert into UserInfo(Userid, Fname, Lname, Email, Phone) 
    values(@userid, @fname, @lname, @Email, @Phone)
```

This is my code....

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["con1"]);
    try
    {
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddUser",con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid",Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text.Trim()));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname",TextBox2.Text) ;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname",TextBox3.Text) ;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email",TextBox4.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone",TextBox5.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Label1.Text = "Record Has Been Added Successfully!";
    }
    catch (Exception en)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Retry to add";
    }
}
```

If I enter `Phone` no value max any eg. 233242342423 it gives error... please how to solve it?

Comment: Why is phone `decimal(18,2)` anyway? Why does it need two decimal places? What about leading zeroes?

Comment: You really shouldn't use `decimal` or any other numeric type for a phone number! Phone numbers are not "numbers", only a sequence of digits.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to define varchar(15) for storing your phone. ( For performance define index on that field)

Comment: This is true, but probably doesn't answer the question.

Comment: if am converting varchar(15)both in column and sp also i got error The conversion of  the varchar value '9881526473' overflowed an int column.

Answer (score 1):

Not only will you lose your leading zeroes but it is bad practice to store phone numbers as integers or doubles. **Use a string** (text field), because you wont be doing any arithmetic on the phone number.

Comment: if am converting varchar(15)both in column and sp also i got error The conversion of  the varchar value '9881526473' overflowed an int column.

Answer (score 0):

The way you used `AddWithValue`, the command assumes all your columns of `string` type (except the first one).

This will not work well for the column:
    `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone",TextBox5.Text)`

which probably not defined as string in the database, so you need to try parsing them explicitly. Note - you need to consider replacing the type for storing your phone (`varchar` will be a good option).

Comment: if am converting varchar(15)both in column and sp also i got error The conversion of  the varchar value '9881526473' overflowed an int column.

Comment: @user3049495 - then you should change the column type in the database.

Answer (score 0):

you should not take phone number data type as decimal.
take phone number as a string and give length like 
phone varchar(18).
it will work.

Comment: if am converting varchar(50)both in column and sp also i got error The conversion of  the varchar value '9881526473' overflowed an int column.

Answer (score 0):

The AddWithValue method converts your value to a SQL data type based on the type of the value that you give it. If the SQL data type is a decimal you need to parse to a .NET decimal for AddWithValue to convert it correctly:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", Decimal.Parse(TextBox5.Text));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have reached the max value of an int in @userid.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

I would suggest using a bigint or alternatively adjusting your approach to the userid column

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).